# Confused with nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have created a simple function to map True or False to a nested list 'visited' depending on the value in nested list 'maze'. I tried to analyse it but not able to figure out why the position (1,0) is updating with True even though position (1,0) has no '=' or '|' value. Any help.

```
def start_matrix(maze):
     visited = [[False]*len(maze[0])]*len(maze)
     print(visited)
     for i in maze:
       for k in i:
          if k == '=' or k == '|':
            print(maze.index(i),i.index(k))
            print(visited[maze.index(i)][i.index(k)])
            visited[maze.index(i)][i.index(k)] = True
            print(visited)
return None
```

Input

```
map1 = [['=',' ','|'],[' ',' ',' ']]
start_matrix(map1)
```

Output:

```
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
0 0
False
[[True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
0 2
False
[[True, False, True], [True, False, True]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue on your code is related to [shallow and deep copies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). When your code assigned visited by doing:

```
visited = [[False] * len(maze[0])] * len(maze)
```

What it's really doing is first creating a list of False (and this is ok, as False is a value type), but then scripting two copies of the list. Lists are objects, so the result is a list with two references to the same list of False. Then when you changed the first inner list, it also changed the second list's values since both were the same.

A fix for this is to change the construction of visited by using a list comprehension to generate two copies of the inner list:

```
visited = [[False] * len(maze[0]) for n in range(len(maze))]
```

Then, the full code will be:

```
def start_matrix(maze):
    visited = [[False] * len(maze[0]) for n in range(len(maze))]
    print(visited)
    for i in maze:
        for k in i:
            if k == '=' or k == '|':
                print(maze.index(i), i.index(k))
                print(visited[maze.index(i)][i.index(k)])
                visited[maze.index(i)][i.index(k)] = True
                print(visited)
    return None

map1 = [['=', ' ', '|'], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
start_matrix(map1)
```

With an output of:

```
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
0 0
False
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False]]
0 2
False
[[True, False, True], [False, False, False]]
```

Hope I'm being clear. If not, please let me know and I'll expand.